# How to extract link's href from a search result?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I tried the quote below, but unable to get the results links...

```
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house-and-apartment/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance"

results = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

links =[]

for el in soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'card__title-link'}):

    links.append(el.find('a').get('href'))

links
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

The links are constructed dynamically from the Json data within the page. To print them, you can do for example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house-and-apartment/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads( soup.find('iw-search')[':results'] )

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data:
    print(d['property']['title'])
    print('https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/{}'.format(d['id']))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
EXCEPTIONAL APARTMENT IN PRIVATE DOMAIN
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8917294
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Proche du parvis Saint-Pierre
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8892312
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
niché au coeur d'un parc privatif proche du parvis Saint-Pie
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8892319
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
niché au coeur d'un parc privatif proche du parvis Saint-Pie
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8892317
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Entre la Maison Communale et "La Rasante" - 2 Logements
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8856902
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Very nice apartment of 87 m² (terrace 13 m²)
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8899851
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
au coeur d'un parc privatif proche du parvis Saint-Pierre, b
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8892306
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New Loft/Apartment - one bedroom + terrace
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8904631
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uccle | Studio, apartments 1-2-3 rooms. & villas
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8917208
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
New 3 bedrooms apartment + parking
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8914953
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LAST OPPORTUNITY and new conditions ! In this penthouse you 
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8909856
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PENTHOUSE 150m² 3 bedrooms + office room with large TERRACE 
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8897103
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wonen in Sint-Niklaas, leven in de stad en tevens genieten v
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8904372
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WONEN AAN DE VREDESBRUG
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8910704
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nouvelle résidence centre-ville de Huy
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8876897
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Magnifique immeuble neuf de 17 entités !
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/6909169
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROJET IMMOBILIER DE STANDING - INTRA MUROS - PRIX DE LANCEM
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/7149936
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 nouvelles constructions à découvrir proche du centre-ville
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/7171388
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apartments For Sale
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8792346
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24 assistentiewoningen en 2 commerciële ruimten
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/7089514
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gerenoveerd 3 slaapkamer appartement
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8912931
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nieuwbouwproject Dockside Gardens - Gent
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8903968
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Projet neuf de 12 appartements de standing
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8717659
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Architecturaal hoogstaand nieuwbouwproject
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/7126544
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2nd Phase of the magnificent project at the best value for m
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8098994
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modern en rustig wonen in Tildonk
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/7128367
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Next to Woluwé's shopping, beautiful project offering views 
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8577833
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modern apartment, design furnished and completely equiped
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8866349
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WOLUWE - APPARTMENT 3 BEDROOMS + PARKING POSSIBLE
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8871919
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nieuwbouwproject Dunant Gardens - Gent
https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/8837221
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, Much appreciated your help here.